# How can I add a subscription for each data in a collection in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently I need to know when a record of a colection was changed, so I use the next code:

```
 db.collection("categories").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
            var categoria = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                categoria.push(doc.data().nombre);
            });
            mandarnotificacion(categoria);
            console.log(": ", categoria.join(","));
        });
```

This code get all records and I want to get the last record updated.
Do you have idea of how can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do as follows:

```
  db.collection('categories').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
      if (change.type === 'added') {
        console.log('added', change.doc.data());
      }
    });
  });
```

See more details in the corresponding [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?authuser=1). In particular, note that "the first query snapshot contains added events for all existing documents that match the query. This is because you're getting a set of changes that bring your query snapshot current with the initial state of the query".

Answer (score 1):

Firestore doesn't have an internal concept of "last record updated".  What you will have to do is add a field that records what you want (probably some sort of timestamp field), and use a query that orders based on that field.  For example:

```
db.collection("categories").orderBy("timestamp", "desc").limit(1)
```

This will give you one document that has the greatest value of the field "timestamp".  If you keep timestamp up to date with the latest update, then your query will always give you the latest updated document.